# How to select timestamp values in PostgreSQL under conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table 'table1' as follows:

`f_key | begin      | counts|
1     | 2018-10-04 | 15    |
1     | 2018-10-06 | 20    |
1     | 2018-10-08 | 34    |
1     | 2018-10-09 | 56    |`

I have another database table 'table2' as follows:

`f_key | p_time     | percent|
1     | 2018-10-05 | 80     |
1     | 2018-10-07 | 90     |
1     | 2018-10-08 | 70     |
1     | 2018-10-10 | 60     |`

The tables can be joined by the `f_key` field.

I want to get a combined table as shown below:

If the `begin` time is earlier than any of the `p_time` then the `p_time` value in the combined table would be the same as `begin` time and the `percent` value would be 50. (As shown in row 1 in the following table)

If the `begin` time is later than any of the `p_time` then the `p_time` value in the combined table would be the very next available `p_time` and the `percent` value would be the corresponding value of the selected `p_time`.
(As shown in row 2, 3 and 4 in the following table)

`row | f_key | begin      | counts| p_time     | percent|
1   | 1     | 2018-10-04 | 15    | 2018-10-04 | 50     |
2   | 1     | 2018-10-06 | 20    | 2018-10-05 | 80     |
3   | 1     | 2018-10-08 | 34    | 2018-10-07 | 90     |
4   | 1     | 2018-10-09 | 56    | 2018-10-08 | 70     |`

Comment: Why the first-row `percent` is `50` instead of `15`?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post if the `begin` time is earlier than any of the `p_time` then the `p_time` value in the combined table would be the same as the `begin` time and the `percent` value would be 50.

Comment: Ok I see I miss the logic I write an answer hope can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use row_number window function to make row number which is the closest row from `table1` by `begin`.

then use `coalesce` function to let `begin` time is earlier than any of the p_time then the p_time value in the combined table would be the same as `begin` time and the `percent` value would be 50

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  f_key INT,
  begin DATE,
  counts INT
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'2018-10-04',15);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'2018-10-06',20);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'2018-10-08',34);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'2018-10-09',56);

CREATE TABLE table2(
  f_key INT,
  p_time DATE,
  percent INT
);


INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, '2018-10-05',80);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, '2018-10-07',90);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, '2018-10-08',70);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, '2018-10-10',60);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY begin) "row",
       t1.f_key,
       t1.counts,
       coalesce(t1.p_time,t1.begin) p_time,
       coalesce(t1.percent,50) percent
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.begin,t1.f_key order by t2.p_time desc) rn,
       t2.p_time,
       t2.percent,
       t1.counts,
       t1.f_key,
       t1.begin
   FROM table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.f_key = t2.f_key and t1.begin > t2.p_time
)t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a319f/5/0)**:

```
| row | f_key | counts |     p_time | percent |
|-----|-------|--------|------------|---------|
|   1 |     1 |     15 | 2018-10-04 |      50 |
|   2 |     1 |     20 | 2018-10-05 |      80 |
|   3 |     1 |     34 | 2018-10-07 |      90 |
|   4 |     1 |     56 | 2018-10-08 |      70 |
```

Comment: I had to add `t1.begin` in the final query. Other than that, it works like a charm! Thank you very much!